# Running VirtualBox 4.2 and PhpVirtualBox 4.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, virtualbox

There are many Tutorials about installing VirtualBox and Phpvirtualbox. In my case non of them has worked. The result is if I open over the Browser the Page is blank. The Source Code has a Code with Javascript Errors.. I can not figure out where the Problem could be.

Please check at first the **Image:**
[image]

Steps I have followed:

**Installing Virtualbox with apt-get:**

```
$ apt-get update  
$ apt-get dist-upgrade
$ apt-get install virtualbox-4.2
```

**Installing Phpvirtualbox**

```
$ apt-get install apache2  
$ apt-get install php5
```

Then  install Phpvirtualbox, setting the permissions of the directory to your username:

```
$ cd /var/www/  
$ wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpvirtualbox/files/phpvirtualbox-4.2-8.zip/download  
$ unzip phpvirtualbox-4.2-8.zip
$ mv phpvirtualbox-4.2-8 phpvirtualbox
$ chown -R vbox:vbox /var/www/phpvirtualbox/
$ cp /var/www/phpvirtualbox/config.php-example /var/www/phpvirtualbox/config.php
```

Then edit /var/www/phpvirtualbox/config.php and set the username and password for the system user that runs VirtualBox:

```
$username = 'vbox';  
$password = 'vbox';
```

**VirtualBox extension pack installation for VRDP support**

```
wget http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.2-8/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.2-8.vbox-extpack  
vboxmanage extpack install Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.2-8.vbox-extpack
```

Start Virtualbox

```
$sudo service vboxweb-service start
```

Comment: This sounds like a question to post in either [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) as it does not seem to have much to do with programming which is [the topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: I solved it by removing Apache and PHP with purge and autoremove.. Installed all again and it is running.